# <li> being cloned with jquery sortable onDrop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested-sortable

> **Attention:** Don't confuse **[jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)** with **[jQuery UI Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/)**

I'm using [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) to `console.log()` every `<li>` of every `<ul>` on the page, but when i rearrange a `<li>`, the console display the element twice

#### This is how the list look like on the page:

[image: html-list-issue]
Everything OK here!

#### This is how the list look like on the console:

[image: html-console-issue]
Here lies the problem!

## HTML code:

```
<div id="cmd_container">
        <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="inclib()">Comando de linha única</button>
        <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="conditional()">Comando de multiplas linhas</button> 
        <button class="w3-btn w3-light-grey" onclick="serialize()">Serializar lista</button>
</div>

<!-- The list -->
<p>Código padrão:</p>
<ul id="lista"></ul>
```

## JS code:

```
$("#lista").sortable();

function serialize() {
    console.clear();
    $.each($("li"), function() {
        console.log($(this).text());
    });
}

// SINGLE LINE COMMAND (DEMO 1)
function inclib() {
    var biblioteca = prompt("Digite o nome da biblioteca:");
    if (biblioteca == "" || biblioteca == null) {
        alert("Digite o nome do comando!");
    } else {
        var html = "" +
            "<li>" + biblioteca + "</li>\n"
        $("#lista").append(html);
    }
}

// MULTIPLE LINES COMMAND (DEMO 2)
function conditional() {
    var condicional = prompt("Digite a expressão conditional:");
    if (condicional == "" || condicional == null) {
        alert("Digite o nome do comando!");
    } else {
        var html = "" +
            "<li>" +
                condicional + " {\n" +
                "<ul></ul>" +
                "\n}" +
            "</li>"
        $("#lista").append(html);
    }
}
```

> **PS:** I've already included all the necessary libraries on the original code:
>
> - jQuery 3.3.1
> - jQuery Sortable

Comment: I think you just got a few extra characters messing up your code. Just remove the `{` of `{\n`, and the `}` of `\n}`.

Comment: The `{` are necessary, as i want to show code on a `<li>`

Comment: How's that? Can you post a working snippet?

Comment: https://s.codepen.io/henriquehbr/debug/OZJKGr/bZrQWyXypRBk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get all li items on the document, if you add two with `inclib` with text: `Command 1` and `Command 2` then you will have the following html:

```
<ul id="lista">
  <li>Command 1<li>
  <li>Command 2</li>
</ul>
```

The you add another using `conditional` with text: `Command 3` then you will have the following html:

```
<ul id="lista">
  <li>Command 1<li>
  <li>Command 2</li>
  <li>Command 3 {
      <ul></li>
  }
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you move `Command 1` or `Command 2` inside `Command 3`, then you will have the following html:

```
<ul id="lista">
  <li>Command 2</li>
  <li>Command 3 {
      <ul>
          <li>Command 1<li>
      </li>
  }
  </li>
</ul>
```

When you select all the li items on your document, using `$("li")`, you will get 3 items, but (in the case i described) the one with a nested ul will return all its content (including the content of the nested li) if you get its text using the jQuery `.text()` function, so you will get the following output:

```
Command 2
Command 3 {
    Command 1
}
Command 1
```

So, if you want to get a text representation of the sortable ul, you should only get the first level li items, using the following selector: `#lista > li`.

Check my working example. Hope it helps.

```js
function serialize() {
   console.clear();
   $.each($("#lista > li"), function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
   });
      var data = $('#lista').sortable("serialize").get();
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, ' '));
  }
  
  // SINGLE LINE COMMAND (DEMO 1)
  function inclib() {
   var biblioteca = prompt("Digite o nome da biblioteca:");
   if (biblioteca == "" || biblioteca == null) {
    alert("Digite o nome do comando!");
   } else {
    var html = "" +
     "<li>" + biblioteca + "</li>\n"
    $("#lista").append(html);
   }
   $('#lista').sortable();
  }
  
  // MULTIPLE LINES COMMAND (DEMO 2)
  function conditional() {
   var condicional = prompt("Digite a expressão conditional:");
   if (condicional == "" || condicional == null) {
    alert("Digite o nome do comando!");
   } else {
    var html = "" +
     "<li>" +
     condicional + " {\n" +
     "<ul></ul>" +
     "\n}" +
     "</li>"
    $("#lista").append(html);
   }
   $('#lista').sortable();
  }
  
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#lista").sortable();
  });
```

```html
<div id="cmd_container">
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="inclib()">Comando de linha única</button>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-blue" onclick="conditional()">Comando de multiplas linhas</button>
  <button class="w3-btn w3-light-grey" onclick="serialize()">Serializar lista</button>
 </div>
 
 
 <p>Código padrão:</p>
 <ul id="lista"></ul>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/js/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>
```

**Edit** According to the [docs](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) you should get a serialized version of the sortable using: `$("#lista").sortable("serialize")` (i added an example to the snippet).